# timer not updating in GUI

Tags: user-interface, timer

Hi I am new to pyqt and am trying to design a multi page GUI. I have tried to implement a multipage GUI with timer in one page. I am able to update timer in a single page GUI but in the below mentioned multi page GUI, the timer is not updating. I apologize if my doubts are trivial but i request to help me so that I can improve my understanding in designing more complex systems

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'page1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_page1(object):
    def setupUi(self, page1):
        page1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page1"))
        page1.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(page1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.go_to_p2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.go_to_p2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 75, 23))
        self.go_to_p2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("go_to_p2"))
        page1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(page1)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        page1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(page1)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        page1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(page1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(page1)

    def retranslateUi(self, page1):
        page1.setWindowTitle(_translate("page1", "MainWindow", None))
        self.go_to_p2.setText(_translate("page1", "Go to Page 2", None))

class Ui_page2(object):
    def setupUi(self, page2):
        page2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page2"))
        page2.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(page2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.X1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.X1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 75, 23))
        self.X1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("X1"))  
        self.X1.clicked.connect(self.doAction)        
        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
        self.step = 0

        self.X2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.X2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 80, 75, 23))
        self.X2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("X2"))
        self.back = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 510, 75, 23))
        self.back.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("back"))        
        self.lcdNumber_x1 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber_x1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber_x1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_x1"))
        self.lcdNumber_x2 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber_x2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 100, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber_x2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_x2"))
        page2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(page2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        page2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(page2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        page2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(page2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(page2)




    def retranslateUi(self, page2):
        page2.setWindowTitle(_translate("page2", "MainWindow", None))
        self.X1.setText(_translate("page2", "X1", None))
        self.X2.setText(_translate("page2", "X2", None))
        self.back.setText(_translate("page2", "Back", None))

    def timerEvent(self, e):
        if self.step >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()
            #self.X1.setText('Finished')
            return
        self.step = self.step + 1
        time.sleep(1)
        self.lcdNumber_x1.display(self.step)

    def doAction(self):
        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.stop()
            self.X1.setText('X1 start')
        else:
            self.timer.start(1000, self.lcdNumber_x1)
            self.X1.setText('X1 stop')



def openWindow(self):
    page1.hide()
    page2.show()

def backWindow(self):
    page2.hide()
    page1.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import time
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    page1 = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_page1()
    ui.setupUi(page1)
    ui.go_to_p2.clicked.connect(openWindow)
    page1.show()

    page2 = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_page2()
    ui.setupUi(page2)    
    ui.back.clicked.connect(backWindow)    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi solved the problem with the following code..

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    # Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'page1.ui'
    #
    # Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
    #
    # WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

    try:
        _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
    except AttributeError:
        def _fromUtf8(s):
            return s

    try:
        _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
    except AttributeError:
        def _translate(context, text, disambig):
            return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

    class Ui_page1(object):
        def setupUi(self, page1):
            page1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page1"))
            page1.resize(800, 600)
            self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(page1)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
            self.go_to_p2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.go_to_p2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 75, 23))
            self.go_to_p2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("go_to_p2"))
            page1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(page1)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
            page1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(page1)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
            page1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(page1)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(page1)

        def retranslateUi(self, page1):
            page1.setWindowTitle(_translate("page1", "MainWindow", None))
            self.go_to_p2.setText(_translate("page1", "Go to Page 2", None))

    class Ui_page2(object):
        def setupUi(self, page2):
            page2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page2"))
            page2.resize(800, 600)
            self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(page2)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
            self.X1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.X1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 75, 23))
            self.X1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("X1"))
            self.X2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.X2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 80, 75, 23))
            self.X2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("X2"))
            self.back = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 510, 75, 23))
            self.back.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("back"))
            self.lcdNumber_x1 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
            self.lcdNumber_x1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 64, 23))
            self.lcdNumber_x1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_x1"))
            self.lcdNumber_x2 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
            self.lcdNumber_x2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 100, 64, 23))
            self.lcdNumber_x2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_x2"))
            page2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(page2)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
            page2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(page2)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
            page2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(page2)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(page2)            

        def retranslateUi(self, page2):
            page2.setWindowTitle(_translate("page2", "MainWindow", None))
            self.X1.setText(_translate("page2", "X1", None))
            self.X2.setText(_translate("page2", "X2", None))
            self.back.setText(_translate("page2", "Back", None))

    class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_page2):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.X1.clicked.connect(self.doAction)
            self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
            self.step = 0

        def on_timeout(self):
            if self.step >= 5:
                self.timer.stop()
                self.X1.setText('Finished')
                #self.back.clicked.connect(backWindow)
                return
            self.step = self.step + 1
            self.lcdNumber_x1.display(self.step)

        def doAction(self):
            if self.timer.isActive():
                self.timer.stop()
                self.X1.setText('Start')
            else:
                self.timer.start(1000)
                self.X1.setText('Stop')

    def openWindow(self):
        page1.close()
        w.show()

        #self.hide()
        #sys.exit(app.exec_())




    def backWindow(self):
        w.hide()
        page1.show()

        #sys.exit(app.exec_())




    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        import time
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

        w= MainWindow()

        page1 = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_page1()
        ui.setupUi(page1)
        ui.go_to_p2.clicked.connect(openWindow)
        page1.show()

        #w= MainWindow()
        #w.show()
        w.back.clicked.connect(backWindow)

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

        #w.back.clicked.connect(backWindow)
        #w.show()


however i have an# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'page1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_page1(object):
    def setupUi(self, page1):
        page1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page1"))
        page1.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(page1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.go_to_p2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.go_to_p2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 75, 23))
        self.go_to_p2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("go_to_p2"))
        page1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(page1)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        page1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(page1)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        page1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(page1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(page1)

    def retranslateUi(self, page1):
        page1.setWindowTitle(_translate("page1", "MainWindow", None))
        self.go_to_p2.setText(_translate("page1", "Go to Page 2", None))

class Ui_page2(object):
    def setupUi(self, page2):
        page2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page2"))
        page2.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(page2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.X1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.X1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 75, 23))
        self.X1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("X1"))
        self.X2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.X2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 80, 75, 23))
        self.X2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("X2"))
        self.back = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 510, 75, 23))
        self.back.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("back"))
        self.lcdNumber_x1 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber_x1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber_x1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_x1"))
        self.lcdNumber_x2 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber_x2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 100, 64, 23))
        self.lcdNumber_x2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_x2"))
        page2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(page2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        page2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(page2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        page2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(page2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(page2)            

    def retranslateUi(self, page2):
        page2.setWindowTitle(_translate("page2", "MainWindow", None))
        self.X1.setText(_translate("page2", "X1", None))
        self.X2.setText(_translate("page2", "X2", None))
        self.back.setText(_translate("page2", "Back", None))

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_page2):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.X1.clicked.connect(self.doAction)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
        self.step = 0

    def on_timeout(self):
        if self.step >= 5:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.X1.setText('Finished')
            #self.back.clicked.connect(backWindow)
            return
        self.step = self.step + 1
        self.lcdNumber_x1.display(self.step)

    def doAction(self):
        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.stop()
            self.X1.setText('Start')
        else:
            self.timer.start(1000)
            self.X1.setText('Stop')

def openWindow(self):
    page1.close()
    w.show()

    #self.hide()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())




def backWindow(self):
    w.hide()
    page1.show()

    #sys.exit(app.exec_())




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import time
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w= MainWindow()

    page1 = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_page1()
    ui.setupUi(page1)
    ui.go_to_p2.clicked.connect(openWindow)
    page1.show()

    #w= MainWindow()
    #w.show()
    w.back.clicked.connect(backWindow)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    #w.back.clicked.connect(backWindow)
    #w.show()
```